# how to avoid loading articles such as AND, OR, IT THE, A during load

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to avoid loading all articles into elastic search during load.  Articles such as AND, OR, THE, A, I, etc.

thanks

i am loading all file content and file names as data.  file names may have "and".  i do not want search includes those articles giving more rows than needed.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend read about [stop words filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html).
Applying filter stopwords your documents will not index words like 'and' or 'the'.

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "filter": [ "stop" ],
  "text": "a quick fox jumps over the lazy dog"
}
```

Tokens

[ quick, fox, jumps, over, lazy, dog ]